# Is 1 hr between arrival in Frankfurt and flight departure with Etihad Airways enough?

Tags: transit, trains, fra

We arrive by train at the TN terminal in Frankfurt and have 1h25 to check in our luggage and catch the plane. Is that enough? We arrive from Cologne and are Belgian.

--- original text follows, above was auto translated:

Nous arrivons en train au terminal TN à Frankfort et avons 1h25 pour enregistrer nos bagages et prendre l’avion. Est ce suffisant? Nous arrivons de Cologne et sommes belges

Comment: This site requires questions and answers in English. Do not worry about bad English (most of us are not native in English). In any case: German trains sometime have huge delays, and for long flights... you should take more time. Do not start travel with stress.

Comment: What do the T&C of your booking say? Typical bag drop cut-off is 60 minutes before departure, and gate closure 30 minutes before departure. Personally I would book an earlier train to avoid the stress of worrying about a late/cancelled train and/or having to run with luggage from the station to check-in. Especially if you are not familiar with Frankfurt airport - its website recommends arriving at least **2.5 hours** before https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/airport-guide/travel-guide.html

Comment: Also, Etihad departs from terminal 2, while the train station is located next to terminal 1, so you have to calculate additional time to get their by bus (i personally would add 30 minutes), because the Skyline is currently closed for construction (until end of June, but you didn't specify your departure date).

Comment: are you travelling with DB? (If so, be aware that their trains are often late, only 66% of trains arrive on time)

Comment: If you want to check the actual punctuality over the last 30 days of your train (ICE or IC) you can punch its number on [Zugfinder](https://www.zugfinder.net/en/start) (I am a mere user of that service, not sponsored)

Comment: Are both rail and flight segments *on the same ticket, issued by the same airline*?   Because if not, Etihad owes you nothing because you didn't show up, and you'd need to buy a replacement ticket.  You might have recourse against the travel agent who booked such a squeaky-tight connection.

Comment: @KateGregory FYI, the [general network policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) is that posts in wrong languages should not be translated, by machine or human - instead they should be simply closed or deleted..

Answer (score 33):

> Is that enough?

No. I strongly recommend against that.

You'll be arriving at "Fernbahnhof" which is pretty far away from the Terminal 1 building and you still need to get to Terminal 2 where Etihad departs. That's quite a trip

From  [here](https://frankfurtairportguide.com/frankfurt-airport-transfers/train/#:%7E:text=Passengers%20at%20Terminal%202%20can,%2C%20Level%201%2C%20Area%20B.)

> Passengers at Terminal 2 can reach the long-distance train station at Frankfurt Airport within 30 minutes. Simply take the Sky Line trains which connect the terminals. They take about 7 to 10 minutes to arrive at their destination and are free to use. Free yellow shuttle buses leave from Terminal 1, Level 1, Area B. Sky Line trains also leave from this area for Terminal 2.

Skyline is closed until June 29th. If you fly before that date you will have to take the shuttle.

Etihad check in Frankfurt closes 1 hour before departure ([link](https://www.etihad.com/en-us/fly-etihad/airport-information))

To make matters worse: German Train reliability has deteriorated significantly. About half of the long distance trains I have taken over the last few years where either significantly delayed or cancelled all together.

So it's not entirely impossible: if you get very lucky at every step along the journey and are fast on your feet (with luggage) you may be able to make it, but I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 11):

That connection will be very difficult to make.  If you did not book the train and plane on one ticket, then Etihad doesn't owe you anything since you did not appear.  They are not responsible for connections they did not book.  You seem to place much value on your time and do not like being delayed at airports.  So I suggest a different approach.

### Build recovery time into your plans.

The airport is served by long-distance trains. However it is also served by short-distance trains - S8 and S9 - into a different station inside the airport.  Short-distance trains tend to be much more reliable on timekeeping - "15 minutes late" is a lot for them.

I would look [closely at the short distance trains](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/transport-and-parking/by-train/local-public-transportation.html) that serve the airport, and find a pleasant location along their route that you can include in your travel plans. For instance both S8 and S9 trains seem to fairly directly serve the Frankfurt city center.

So I would plan my travel so that the long-distance train takes me into Frankfurt. I would plan hours of pleasant activities such as restaurants, museums and shopping.  Then plan to take the short distance rail to the airport to arrive [at the recommended time](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/airport-guide/travel-guide.html). The short train is unlikely to be greatly delayed. (and if it is delayed, take a taxi cab).

This leisure period serves as "recovery time" if the long-haul train is delayed. If it is late, you must sacrifice some of your leisure time in Frankfurt, but you will still be able to take your short-haul train on time to the airport, and arrive as planned.  You miss a museum, instead of your flight :)